# How to call Leaflet FullScreen plug-in from code

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm currently using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) along with [leaflet.fullscreen](http://github.com/brunob/leaflet.fullscreen/) to provide a full screen map.

I've got it working nicely with the button but I can't work out how to "call" the function manually from my JavaScript code.

I've tried: `map.fullscreenControl.toogleFullScreen();` but get the following error and a "broken" fullscreen:

```
TypeError: this.invalidateSize is not a function
this.invalidateSize();
```

Comment: Typo?? map.fullscreenControl.**toggleFullScreen**();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no answers and still struggling I switched to a different plugin [Leaflet.fullscreen](https://github.com/mapbox/Leaflet.fullscreen)
.

It seems a lot more straightforward, however I did need to tweek the CSS for < IE9.

Answer (score 1):

You could trigger a click on its fullscreen button. 
For example with jQuery:

```
$(".leaflet-control-zoom-fullscreen")[0].click();
```

Comment: Recent Browsers won't let you do that. IE: Chrome would say:  "Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture."

Answer (score 0):

I use library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@runette/leaflet-fullscreen
and the following code:

[image]

successfully !